# Bootstrap Datepicker, obtener la fecha al pulsar un día del calendario cuando está en modo "embeded"

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, datepicker

Estoy usando Bootstrap Datepicker creado a traves de la [página Sandbox](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=embedded&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox) en modo embeded, es decir que por default se muestra en la página tal como se ve en la captura.[image: datepicker]

Especifico la versión que uso:

```
/*!
 * Datepicker for Bootstrap v1.9.0 (https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap- 
datepicker)
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License v2.0 
(http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)
 */
```

y el código:

```
<div class="row" id="sandbox-container">
  <div class="col-12"></div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sandbox-container div').datepicker({
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn: "linked",
        language: "es",
        daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
        todayHighlight: true
    });
});
```

Necesito que al pulsar cualquier día me salte un alert con la fecha específica de ese día, mes y año. He visto un Fiddle que resuelve el problema, pero parece que no es una versión actual porque no me funcionan las opciones.
Alguien sabe cómo puedo obtener esos valores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

revisando la [documentación](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/events.html), se genera un evento llamado *changeDate* cuando el usuario selecciona alguna fecha, el manejador del evento es el siguiente

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
   .on("changeDate", function(e) {

});
```

Modificando tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sandbox-container div').datepicker({
      weekStart: 1,
      todayBtn: "linked",
      language: "es",
      daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
      todayHighlight: true
  }).on("changeDate", function(e) {
     alert("Seleccionaste " + e.date.getDate() + " de " + e.date.getMonth() + " del " + e.date.getUTCFullYear());
  });
});
```

Te dejo un [link](https://codepen.io/checosele/pen/jONYLob) del ejemplo funcionando, utilizando la versión 1.9.0 de Datepicker for Bootstrap.